# Why does Autofac.config fail to load in [ClassInitialize] when running all tests?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, config, autofac, mstest

I have a class initialize method that runs sets up an autofac.config amoung other dependencies in mstest. When I run the tests in the file individually they pass. however when I run the tests together I get the following error:

> "The configuration file 'autofac.config' was not found and is not optional.":null`

```
var applicationPath = new Uri(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
var msContainerBuilder = new Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder();
msContainerBuilder.AddXmlFile(Path.Combine(applicationPath,"autofac.config"));

var msContainer = msContainerBuilder.Build();
var module = new Autofac.Configuration.ConfigurationModule(msContainer);
containerBuilder.RegisterModule(module);
```

I am completely lost as to what is causing this. Can anybody help solve this issue?

**Edit:**
Opening up the msContainerBuilder object gives the same information whether the tests are run individually or all at once.

Comment: It is throwing this error because you didn't prefix the `autofac.config` file name with a folder name. Therefore it is dependent upon the context it is run in and prone to failure.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I have edited the file as above and the same issue persists.

Comment: A `Uri` for a local system path? I suggest you step through the code to make sure the path being built actually exists.